# Installing Python package h5py in MinGW/MSYS2 throws ImportError

Tags: python, windows, mingw, msys

I installed h5py through the package mingw64-i686-python-h5py in MSYS2. Importing it in a MinGW shell throws the following error:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr  9 2020, 14:12:45)  [GCC 9.3.0 32 bit] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import h5py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import version
  File "C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/version.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import h5 as _h5
  File "h5py/h5.pyx", line 1, in init h5py.h5
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing defs: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Reinstalling the package did not fix it. I installed numpy the same way and it works just fine.

Comment: It's broken for me, too (in 64 bits). I recommend reporting a bug at https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues.